# Identity specification in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как в БД Oracle при создании таблицы настроить поле ID с PK и автоматической генерацией числа. Спасибо.

Comment: В Oracle для этого нужен триггер + последовательность. Таблицу создаёте когда подключаетесь через что? в OracleSqlDeveloper в режиме Advanced создания таблицы, достаточно выбрать поле для ПК и поставить галочку и триггер и последовательность создадутся автоматом.

Comment: Покажите, как создаете таблицу или приложите скрипт создания

Comment: @4per Таблицу создаю в TOAD.

Comment: @lDrakonl `CREATE TABLE GRAPH
(
  UKEY     INTEGER,
  U_RUL    INTEGER,
  K        INTEGER,
  T        DATE,
  H4       NUMBER,
  H1       NUMBER,
  V1       NUMBER,
  V2       NUMBER,
  V3       NUMBER,
  V4       NUMBER,
  VM       NUMBER,
  T1       NUMBER,
  T2       NUMBER,
  T3       NUMBER,
  T4       NUMBER,
  DL       INTEGER,
  IREZ     INTEGER,
  FREZ     NUMBER,
  LOGBITS  INTEGER
)`

Comment: @lDrakonl но я еще пробовал и в TOAD создавать ... там ставлю галочку еще на PK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В версии до 12го оракла придется дополнительно создать последовательность и триггер. Вместе это выглядит примерно так:
Создание таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE GRAPH ( 
  UKEY INTEGER, 
  U_RUL INTEGER, 
  ....
  LOGBITS INTEGER )
```

Добавление индекса:

```
ALTER TABLE GRAPH ADD (CONSTRAINT GRAPH_PK PRIMARY KEY (UKEY));
```

Создание последовательности:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE graph_seq START WITH 1;
```

Создание триггера:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER graph_id 
BEFORE INSERT ON GRAPH
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT graph_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.UKEY
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

В 12 версии Оракла можно при создании таблицы сразу написать так:

```
CREATE TABLE GRAPH (UKEY INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY, 
               ...
               );
```

Comment: спасибо работает, только не пойму, если я удалю из таблице поля, то ключ продолжается с последнего который был ну например было 8 записей я их все удалил, добавляю новую и получаю ключ с номером 9 на не 1  почему так ?

Comment: Там внутри последовательность, которая отдает номера по порядку. И если она отдала номер 8, то следующий будет 9. Это не зависит от таблицы, в которой удаляются строки. Обычно для поля с ID важна уникальность, а порядок цифр не важны. Если мое пояснение не понятно, то лучше почитать про последовательности